# Delay to recreate an data extension using active query in Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, integration

I am using the Query Activity to create an extension date from another date extension, but it is taking over 3 minutes to perform When run in automation studio, date extension origin has only 11 records.

When I run the query just outside the studio automation executes immediately.

Does anyone have any idea what should I check?

What time standard to run a simple query and copy a few records to a new extension of data?

Query

```
SELECT 
    t.[Conta pessoal: ContactIDMC],
    t.[ID da oportunidade],
    t.Email,
    t.Fase,
    t.[Data inicio do processo],
    t.[Data do Fim do Processo],
    t.[Duração da fase],
    t.[Duração],
    t.[Status do Processo Seletivo] as 'Status do Processo Seletivo',
    Dateadd(d, -7, t.[Data do Vestibular]) as 'EstaChegando',
    Dateadd(d, -8, t.[Data do Vestibular]) as 'Institucional1',
    'false' as Sent,
    DATEADD(hour , 3, Getdate()) as Datacriacao

from VestibularInscritos t WITH (NOLOCK)
```

I'm having trouble because I have to take the following steps, and to perform only 2 steps takes more than 3 minutes.

```
1- Import report from the salesforce to Date Extension
2- Create new date extension with calculated fields from item 1
3- Create new targeted extension data from item 2
4- Send e-mail
```

[image: automation 1]

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't necessarily indicate an issue with your query and it's probably not something that you can fix.

When an Automation is run, messages are sent to different queues to run the Automation Activities in your Automation. Depending on when you run the Automation, there could be a transient delay as there are millions of messages sent to queues each hour on a stack (from different accounts on the stack). My recommendation would be to test again later. I've found Automation performance to be pretty good on the whole, but sometimes they take a little longer than you might expect.

Comment: I understand and appreciate the answer,
It happens that the delay is only in the generation of date extension, I am not sending anything. Sometimes it takes 15 seconds and sometimes takes 4 minutes. see picture? @eliotharper

Comment: Yes I do. Again, this is most likely not related to your specific Activity, but is related to the number of concurrent tasks being processed by queues on your stack which is shared across many accounts. If these delays are occurring consistently then my advice would be to open a support request so the operations team can investigate why this performance impact is consistently occurring.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the explanation, I have another doubt. It is normal delay when I am performing only the segmentation of subscribers Example: Select * from Data1 to Data2, with only 15 records, sometimes it takes 15 seconds to 15 minutes to perform this copy, without sending email ...

Comment: Can you try including all your field names in the SELECT statement instead of using asterisk (*)? I have noticed that there's a performance impact when you use asterisk. From speaking to a data developer on the Marketing Cloud engineering team, they have to run several validation tasks before the query is executed and I think this may be slowing you down. Can you confirm?

Comment: Exemple: Dateadd(d, -7, t.[Data do Vestibular]) as 'EstaChegando', ??
t.[ID da oportunidade], to t.[ID da oportunidade] as 'Id da Oportunidade', ?

Comment: I posted an complete query, please see above,

Comment: I can't see why this would impact performance. I'd suggest raising a support case.

Comment: Already tried with support, could not a good explanation for this delay,
especially when I'm performing a copy of an extension date to another date extension with few records (less than twenty), arrives to take 5 minutes. I have an automation with 4 steps, Import Report SF> Query> Query> Email,,, gets to take 15 minutes and sometimes 30 seconds,,,
Do not understand! Tks for help!

Comment: Can you send me an query exemple?
You can check how long takes to create a copy of an data extension?